# SAS Input from .txt where input spans multiple lines

Tags: sas

everyone.

I have a question that is driving me crazy.

Say I have 2 text files that look like this:

File_one.txt:

```
Name_sample_f1       *spans one line 
File_sample_f1       *spans one line 
String_sample_f1     *spans multiple, varying lines until the end of the file 
String_sample_f1
```

File_two.txt:

```
Name_sample_f2       *spans one line 
File_sample_f2       *spans one line 
String_sample_f2     *spans multiple, varying lines until the end of the file 
String_sample_f2 
String_sample_f2 
String_sample_f2
```

I would like to input both of them into a dataset named *test* and take the following form:

```
    Name             File             String
    ----             ----             ------
1   Name_sample_f1   File_sample_f1   String_sample_f1 
                                      String_sample_f1 
2   Name_sample_f2   File_sample_f2   String_sample_f2 
                                      String_sample_f2 
                                      String_sample_f2 
                                      String_sample_f2
```

I appreciate it ahead of time if anyone can help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do it quite as complicatedly as three datasteps (especially if you're going to do N files).  It's pretty easy, really.  Use the EOV indicator (End of Volume) to see when you're at the start of a new file [EOV is tripped *after* ending a volume/file] and each time you're at the start of a new file, read the name and filename in the first two lines.

```
data test;
format name filename $100.;
retain name filename line;
infile '("c:\temp\file1.txt", "c:\temp\file2.txt")' eov=end lrecl=100 pad truncover; *or use wildcards, like infile "c:\temp\file*.txt";
input a $ @;
put _all_;
if (_n_=1) or (end=1) then do;
  end=0;
  line=1;
end;
else line+1;
if line=1 then do;
  input @1 name $100.;
end;
else if line=2 then do;
  input @1 filename $100.;
end;
else do;
  input @1 string $100.;
  output;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Edit*  I an having the same problem with this one.  It is giving me multiple observations/records instead of just one for each file

Answer (score 0):

```
filename file1 'testfile1.txt';
filename file2 'testfile2.txt';

DATA file1;
LENGTH thisname thisfile thistext $ 200;
RETAIN thisname thisfile;
linecounter=0;
DO UNTIL(eof);
  INFILE file1 end = eof;
  INPUT;
  linecounter+1;
  IF (linecounter eq 1) THEN thisname=_infile_;
  ELSE IF (linecounter eq 2) then thisfile=_infile_;
  ELSE DO;
     thistext=_infile_;
     output;
  END;
END;
RUN;


DATA file2;
LENGTH thisname thisfile thistext $ 200;
RETAIN thisname thisfile;
linecounter=0;
DO UNTIL(eof);
  INFILE file2 end = eof;
  INPUT;
  linecounter+1;
  IF (linecounter eq 1) THEN thisname=_infile_;
  ELSE IF (linecounter eq 2) then thisfile=_infile_;
  ELSE DO;
     thistext=_infile_;
     output;
  END;
END;
RUN;

DATA all_files;
SET file1 file2;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=all_files; RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..

Comment: I appreciate this as well, but it is not actually doing what I want it to do.I appreciate this as well, but it is not actually doing what I want it to do.